# reference folder in docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's the folder structure for my project:

```
project
  env_files
    global.env
    vpn.env
  gluetun
    docker-compose.yaml
```

The docker-compose has the following line.

```
env_file:
  - fileName: ../env_files/vpn.env
```

When I run the compose file in gluetun I get the following error "services.gluetun-protonvpn.env_file.0 must be a string".

If I wrap is in double quotes, will it be able to figure out that it's a directory up?

-- UPDATE --
Here's my vpn.env file

```
NORDVPN_SERVICEUSER=--myusername--
NORDVPN_SERVICEPASS=--mypassword--
PROTONVPN_SERVICEUSER=--myusername--
PROTONVPN_SERVICEPASS=--mypassword--
```

In my compose I have.

```
- OPENVPN_USER=${PROTONVPN_SERVICEUSER}
```

However when I run the container I get this error.

```
WARN[0000] The "PROTONVPN_SERVICEUSER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "PROTONVPN_SERVICEPASS" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Please help!

Comment: The Compose [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) directive just takes a list of file names, not objects with a `fileName:` key; delete the `fileName:` part.  You can quote the string or not as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one environment file, you can simply do

```
env_file: ../env_files/vpn.env
```

If you have multiple files, you can do

```
env_file:
  - ../env_files/file1.env
  - ../env_files/file2.env
  - ../env_files/file3.env
```

Docs are [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file).